# Unexpected Warning when Assigning Bit-field to Variable

Tags: c, visual-studio

This portion of code

```
typedef struct
{
   unsigned int a : 1;
} bitfield_t;

bitfield_t bitfield = {1};
unsigned char c = bitfield.a;
```

when compiled with Visual Studio 2019 `cl /TC /W4 main.c` produces the warning `'initializing': conversion from 'unsigned int' to 'unsigned char', possible loss of data`

I don't understand how there can be a loss of data when assigning from a 1-bit field to an 8-bit variable. Does the C standard not guarantee that this assignment be possible and have the expected value `c == 1`?

Comment: That looks like a quirk in the compiler generating an inappropriate error (warning) message.

Comment: It is not caused by bit-fields; MSVC warns the same way with `unsigned int x = 1; unsigned char c = x;`. (Even though the bit-field says to use only 1 bit to store the value, its type is still `unsigned int`.) MSVC is simply not making use of information about the origin of the `unsigned int` when considering it is being assigned to an `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your struct field is an `unsigned int`, `int` is typically 4 bytes wide in memory while `unsigned char` is typically 1 byte wide. The actual sizes depend on the compiler but what matters is that `int` uses more bytes than `char`.

So this message is accurate, you're chopping off 3 bytes when assigning an `int` to a `char`.

Comment: No, you are not chopping any bytes. This one is only 1 bit long. Visual studio compiler is not the very best one